# Getting max values from MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have three tables:

1. competitions (id, name, date)
2. athletes (id,name)
3. results (place, id_athlete, id_competition, ranking_points)

where:

```
results.id_athlet=athlet.id
results.id_competition=competitions.id
```

I need a query to select the latest `ranking_points` of each athlete based on `competitions.date`.

Comment: Do you want just the ranking points awarded to an athlete in the latest competition, or a total of all an athlete's ranking points up to the competition date?

Could you provide some example data, and examples of the output you'd like?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this depends on what date range you pick

EXAMPLE : Ranking Points Since The Beginning of the Month for Competition 'Kids Only'

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        A.name Athlete,R.ranking_points Rank,C.`date` CompDate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id,`date` FROM competitions
        WHERE name = 'Kids Only' AND `date` >=
        DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL (DAY(DATE(NOW()))-1) DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND;
    ) C
    INNER JOIN results R ON C.id = R.id_competition
    INNER JOIN athletes A ON R.id_athlete = A.id
) AA
ORDER BY Rank DESC;
```

EXAMPLE : Teenage Rankings For the Week of 2012-10-08 - 2012-10-15

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        A.name Athlete,R.ranking_points Rank,C.`date` CompDate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id,`date` FROM competitions
        WHERE name = 'Teenage'
        AND `date` >= DATE('2012-10-08') + INTERVAL 0 SECOND
        AND `date` <  DATE('2012-10-15') + INTERVAL 0 SECOND
    ) C
    INNER JOIN results R ON C.id = R.id_competition
    INNER JOIN athletes A ON R.id_athlete = A.id
) AA
ORDER BY Rank DESC;
```

I hope these give you a basis to start...